# sqoop job hangs on database enterprise 4.8.7

Tags: cassandra, datastax, sqoop, datastax-enterprise

Have 6 nodes cassandra cluster from which one node is running in analytics mode and rest other in search modes.
Using DSE sqooop to load data from oracle 11g database to cassandra sample keyspace using command:

dse sqoop cql-import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port:servicename --username  --password  --table TEST --cassandra-keyspace test --cassandra-table test_table --cassandra-column-mapping id:ID,name:NAME --cassandra_host  --verbose

Note: /tmp/sqoop-cassandra/compile/87h70484m9mfkfl79/TEST.java used or overrides a deprecated API .
Note : Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Job keep on above state with no other output or errors and stays forever.

When we check on oracle database side session on oracle side stays inactive with waiting event sqlnet message from client .

Table structure is very simple with two columns ( test on oracle and test_table on cassandra)
Table structure in oracle side : id number( primary key) , name varchar()

Table structure on Cassandra : id int ( primary key ), name text

Keyspace defination is network topology with one replication factor on the nodes which is running as analytics node.

I have spend couple of days to find the reason of this issues - why job hangs and session on oracle side remain in-active. Kindly help on this issues